# Are the Curses of Earth natural?

Tags: madoka-magica

At the end of the anime series, when Madoka remade the Universe for Puella Magi to be saved before becoming Witches, Homura says that with Witches being gone Wraiths take their place because Madoka only stopped the Witches from being born and not eliminated the Curses of Earth.

in the Rebellion Movie when Homura transcended and becomes a goddess too, she chooses not to erase the Incubators from existence but rather give them the purpose of managing Earth's Curses (thus seemingly eliminating the existence of the Wraiths and what work Puella Magi needed to do)

Considering that the Curses of Earth were manifested in Witches first, are these curses natural? or is it a result of the Incubators? (ie. bring them to earth or a result of having created Puella Magi/Witches)